# Erro na hora de efetuar a soma dentro do foreach

Tags: c#

Eu tenho esse método `CadastroDespesas`, só que ele está efetuando a soma errado no `foreach` que percorre a minha lista.

Eu não sei o que é, se alguém puder me ajudar...

*A* `totdesp` *é uma variável global declarada na minha classe).*

```
class Ex4
{
    List<String> descricaodespesas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valordespesas = new List<float>();
    List<String> descricaoreceitas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valorreceitas = new List<float>();
    float totdesp, totreceit;
    float mediareceit, mediadesp;

    public void CadastroDespesas()
    {
        string descricao;
        float valor,somadesp = 0;
        Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
        valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        valordespesas.Add(valor);
        Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
        descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
        descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);
        foreach (float som in valordespesas)
        {
            somadesp += valor;
        }
        totdesp = somadesp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117)

Comment: Leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Answer (score 3):

O erro é que você está percorrendo corretamente o `valordespesas` mas sempre soma o mesmo valor; você precisa adicionar `som`, não `valor`:

```
foreach (float som in valordespesas)
{
    somadesp += som;
}
```

Comment: Vlw Amigo, resolveu o problema aqui. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeSchubertMedeiros, se a resposta tá correta, marca como aceita ;)

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção é nem usar o `foreach()` e sim o metodo `Sum()`

```
totdesp = valordespesas.Sum();
```